# Secure RSS Feeds stopped working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rss

We're pulling information from this feed:
https://wazcommunity.wordpress.com/feed/

Until a few days ago it worked like a charm and other unsecure feeds are still working fine. I found the following error messages in the uls log:

> ProtocolError occurred trying to complete the request. The server returned a status code of : Forbidden and the status description is : "Forbidden"
>       RssWebPart: Exception handed to HandleRuntimeException.HandleException System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetHierarchicalXPathNavigator(IHierarchicalDataSource ds)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)

Strangely enough it's still working in our Test environment (which is identical except for the fact, that it doesn't use `https` itself.

We're not using a proxy and when we try to open the feed using Internet Explorer everything looks good.

Comment: did you update the web.config for proxy settings?check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7f1f6025-7978-4f3c-b684-d0f8397b863c/rss-viewer-webpart-problem?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: We're not using a proxy and there is no proxy defined in the web.config at all, only "<system.net><defaultProxy /></system.net>"